# Send notifications to my website code so my function can run, like scheduling

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase, is it possible to send notifications to my website code so my function can run, like scheduling?

I have a function that needs to run once a day in my front end code. I don't have a backend Node.js setup, just Firebase and my front end website hosted with Firebase.

I'm open for other options also. I'm not sure if Firebase has any new functions. I'm aware that I can listen to Firebase Database for changes.

I also know that [https://zapier.com](https://zapier.com/) could populate a table in my database for me to listen to, but I'm looking for something slightly simpler and better.

Tech I'm using: Angular 2, TypeScript and Firebase

Comment: Are you looking for this "website code" to be run on an action from somewhere else? Or at a scheduled time?

Comment: a scheduled time, so the same time everyday and only once run.

Comment: Firebase itself has no scheduling functionality as far as I'm aware. You can spin up a different worker process though (not sure what stack you're running) at a scheduled time using a slew of libraries though

Comment: @BHendricks do you mean a web worker? I'm using angular 2 with typescript and firebase

Comment: Yes. Depending on what hosting your using, I know heroku has a worker scheduling add-on that works pretty well

Comment: @BHendricks I'm hosting with firebase and storing my database with them. I could use jquery web worker support?

Comment: Ya, I'm not sure. I haven't hosted anything directly on firebase

Comment: @BHendricks could i use setTimeout in my angular 2 code or would this cause troubles with memory etc?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good solution, no, if you want actions performed on a scheduled basis...

Comment: @BHendricks is there a solution with localstorage I could use? although this function i need to run is more an admin feature

Comment: Is there a browser somewhere with your web application running at all times? If there is, then yes a setTimeout solution would work. If not, then you need to schedule "something else" to load your web application and trigger the action that you want run.

Comment: But really. What you want to do should likely be put on the server side. I understand that you have limitations preventing you from doing that, but maybe you should work on the limitations instead of around them.